# jspdf to create a pdf in angular issue

Tags: angular, promise, jspdf

The pdf gets created fine using ng serve locally but I get the below error on the server. Can some one help. I have tried modifying the code but no luck. I have a sample of the code as well below. When I run the app on the server without the jspdf call the site works fine but adding this causes the below error. It has to do with the jspdf call.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]
    at resolvePromise (main.js:14845
1:21)
    at main.js:148346:11
    at main.js:148363:27
    at main.js:275791:24
    at main.js
:147457:160)
    at Object.onInvoke (main.js:2277
67:25)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (main.js
:147457:48)
    at Zone.run (main.js:147183:37) 
    at main.js:148524:28
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (mai
n.js:147490:173) {
  rejection: undefined,
  promise: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
    __zone_symbol__state: 0,
    __zone_symbol__value: undefined
  },
     _name: 'angular',
    _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
    _zoneDelegate: <ref *2> _ZoneDelegate {
      _taskCounts: [Object],
      zone: [Circular *1],
      _parentDelegate: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _forkZS: null,
      _forkDlgt: null,
      _forkCurrZone: null,
      _interceptZS: null,
      _interceptDlgt: null,
      _interceptCurrZone: null,
      _invokeZS: [Object],
      _invokeDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _invokeCurrZone: [Circular *1],
      _handleErrorZS: [Object],
      _handleErrorDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular *1],
      _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
      _scheduleTaskDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
      _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
      _invokeTaskDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
      _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
      _cancelTaskDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
      _hasTaskZS: [Object],
      _hasTaskDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular *2],
      _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1]
    }
  },
  task: ZoneTask {
    _zone: <ref *1> Zone {
      _parent: [Zone],
      _name: 'angular',
      _properties: [Object],
      _zoneDelegate: [_ZoneDelegate]
    },
    runCount: 0,
    _zoneDelegates: null,
    _state: 'notScheduled',
    type: 'microTask',
    source: 'Promise.then',
    data: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
      __zone_symbol__state: true,
      __zone_symbol__value: undefined
    },
    scheduleFn: undefined,
    cancelFn: undefined,
    callback: [Function (anonymous)],
    invoke: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
}
```

I tried the below code and am not having any luck. some one please take a look. Is there a better way to create a pdf in angular. I would appreciate any help

```
let doc = new jsPDF({hotfixes: ["px_scaling"], unit: "pt"})
doc.html(this.pdfHtml, {
  html2canvas: {
    scale: 1,
  },
  callback: function (doc) {
    doc.save(`Ti_Summary.pdf`, {returnPromise: true}).then(response => {
      console.log('Document Downloaded')
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  },
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
})
```

Comment: share your package.json as well

Answer (score 0):

***- :For Angular 11/12: -***

Installing the library in your project: -

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

Now, Creating an Element Reference which can be bind to HTML Element (div).

Your Component `.ts` file `(example.component.ts)` should look like: -

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

export class ExampleComponent { 
   @ViewChild('myTemp') myTempRef: ElementRef;

   print(){
    const DATA = this.myTempRef.nativeElement;
    html2canvas(DATA).then(canvas => {        
      let fileWidth = 200;
      let fileHeight = canvas.height * fileWidth / canvas.width;
      
      const FILEURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
      let PDF = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      let position = 0;
      PDF.addImage(FILEURI, 'PNG', 5, 5, fileWidth, fileHeight)      
      PDF.save('angular-demo.pdf');
    });   
   }
}
```

Now, .html file must be bind with the template reference 'myTempRef'.

Your Component .html file `(example.component.html)` should look like: -

```
<div #myTemp>
   // other code here

  <button (click)="print()"></button>
</div>
```